# If cell contains text wildcard - excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to use an IF statement to find a string of text with a wildcard in a particular cell. E.g.

```
=IF(OR(K3="Fixed Rate*", K3="Mobile Rate*"), "true", "false")
```

I have also tried something like this:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Fixed Rate*",K3))
```

But everything seems to end up in "*false*". Ideally, I would like to find if a particular cell has either wildcard of *Fixed Rate*... or wildcard of *Mobile Rate*...

Does anyone know why and have a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there. Try this:

```
=OR(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("fixed rate",K3))),NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("mobile rate",K3))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining your two ideas produces the right result.

`=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Fixed Rate*",K3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Mobile Rate*",K3))), "true", "false")`

You need to use the `SEARCH` function to allow wildcards, then the `OR` function to check for the presence of either string.

Answer (score 1):

Credits to @Olly. You could also do it like:

```
=OR(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH("*Fixed Rate*",K3,0))),NOT(ISERROR(MATCH("*Mobile Rate*",K3,0))))
```